# GitHub remote removed from repo after using set-url

Tags: git, github, git-remote, bitbucket-server

I want to use an open source project from Github repository in my project which is placed on Atlassian Stash.
But I know that I have to do some change on that project in order to be usable in mine. Furthermore I do want to be able to add future patches of that GitHub repository to my project.
I have cloned the code to my local computer using following command:

```
git clone http://github.com/...
```

after that I added that code to my stash using following command:

```
git remote set-url origin http://MY-LOCAL_STASH/...
git push origin master
```

after doing that just the code placed on the server and GitHub git trackers were removed by git itself.
Does anyone have any solution for my problem?

Comment: It took me considerable time to realize that https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash is a product, not a git stash

Comment: @sehe yeah I dunno who thought that that name would be a good idea, took me forever to realize it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `set-url` the URL for the `origin` remote, you removed the original location, which is that of the GitHub repository.  In Git, you can have [many remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), and the default name for the one you cloned from is `origin`.

You should add another remote (I usually call it `upstream`) and point it to GitHub.  To update the copy of the code in Stash, you'll [pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) from `upstream` then [push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to `origin`.  Run this:

```
git remote add upstream http://github.com/...
git fetch upstream
```

(Substitute the URL of the repo you cloned from.)  Now you can do this whenever you want to update:

```
git fetch upstream
git push origin upstream/master
```